# Can I save this dire-looking plant?

Tags: plant-care

Last summer, a plant has been offered to me, supposedly unkillable.

However, I am not one to back away from a challenge, and a winter later, it looks quite dead to me.

[image]

However, there seem to be a sliver a green left, so I wonder if I can try and save it.

[image]

Is it possible to save it? If so, how should I tackle this?

Comment: If it is a Cordyline, it looks more like a dead Cordyline australis to me - what part of the world are you in? Is there a short, straight trunk at the base,or does all the growth arise out of the soil with no trunk at all?

Comment: You certainly proved them wrong, didn't you! I appreciate your gumption!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plant is [Cordyline australis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordyline_australis) sometimes known as a Spike or the Cabbage palm. It comes from New Zealand and is commonly sold as an annual as it is only winter hardy to  USDA Zones 9-11.  If you should happen to live where it gets below 20 degrees F then this plant is dead.  Even if it is not dead it will be a long time, if ever, before it looks nice.

I recommend sending this one to the recycle bin.  If you should get another plant like this:

- grow in part shade
- bring inside in the winter and place near bright light
  -keep container soils consistently moist in summer but reduce moisture indoors in winter. 
  After a while it might look like this

[image]

Care from [here](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=282311)

Comment: @Bamboo thanks for correcting me on the species

Comment: Hmm, well that isn't what I was doing... the comment/question was directed at the OP rather than you - for all I know, this is a phormium rather than cordyline,  hence the query re the trunk. As its to all intents and purposes dead, its hard to be sure what it might once have been.